# Get color property while ColorDialog still open, before confirming the dialog?

Tags: .net, vb.net, colors, dialog, colordialog

What I want to do is while a ColorDialog is opened, get the temporal selected color in the "full open" mode of the Colordialog.

For example in this image I have a white colored picturebox and a ColorDialog is opened with the "Red" color selected, what I want is to change the picturebox backcolor to the selected color (Red) without pressing the "ok" button to confirm the ColorDialog and to get the Color result...

[image]

This is possibly to do with the default ColorDialog?

This is what I've tried:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents PicBox As New PictureBox
    Dim ColorDlg As New ColorDialog

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PicBox.BackColor = Color.Blue
        ColorDlg.FullOpen = True
        Me.Controls.Add(PicBox)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PicBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PicBox.Click
        ColorDlg.Color = sender.backcolor
        While Not ColorDlg.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
            sender.BackColor = ColorDlg.Color
        End While
        ' sender.BackColor = ColorDlg.Color
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I believe it's easier to build your colorDialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: **Just because we can, doesn't mean we should!**

This example is specifically designed to work with the `ColorDialog` in the `FullOpen` mode.  It relies on the fact that the "Red:", "Green:" and "Blue:" `Edit` controls in the dialog are updated in real-time as the color is changed by the user, and the fact that a `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` is sent each time those controls are updated (this also applies to when those values are manually typed in).  We have to create a new instance of `MyColorDialog` each time we want to use it so that the window handles to those controls are correct.

The `WindowsEnumerator` class below is based on Bob's (TheLearnedOne) work [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_23357525.html#a21455629).

*I'm `Idle_Mind` over at Experts-Exchange as well.

This was tested on Win8 Pro in VS2010 Premium.  I don't if any changes would need to be made for the ColorDialog in other versions of Windows:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents PicBox As New PictureBox
    Private WithEvents ColorDlg As MyColorDialog = Nothing

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PicBox.BackColor = Color.Blue
        Me.Controls.Add(PicBox)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PicBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PicBox.Click
        ColorDlg = New MyColorDialog
        ColorDlg.Color = sender.backcolor
        If ColorDlg.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            sender.BackColor = ColorDlg.Color
        End If
        ColorDlg = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub ColorDlg_CurrentColor(c As System.Drawing.Color) Handles ColorDlg.CurrentColor
        PicBox.BackColor = c
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class MyColorDialog
    Inherits ColorDialog

    Public Event CurrentColor(ByVal c As Color)

    Private Const GA_ROOT As Integer = 2
    Private Const WM_CTLCOLOREDIT As Integer = &H133

    Public Declare Function GetAncestor Lib "user32.dll" _
        (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal gaFlags As Integer) As IntPtr

    Private EditWindows As List(Of ApiWindow) = Nothing

    Public Sub New()
        Me.FullOpen = True
    End Sub

    <System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSetAttribute(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
    Protected Overrides Function HookProc(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        Select Case msg
            Case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT
                If IsNothing(EditWindows) Then
                    Dim mainWindow As IntPtr = GetAncestor(hWnd, GA_ROOT)
                    If Not mainWindow.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
                        EditWindows = New List(Of ApiWindow)((New WindowsEnumerator).GetChildWindows(mainWindow, "Edit"))
                    End If
                End If

                If Not IsNothing(EditWindows) AndAlso EditWindows.Count = 6 Then
                    Dim strRed As String = WindowsEnumerator.WindowText(EditWindows(3).hWnd)
                    Dim strGreen As String = WindowsEnumerator.WindowText(EditWindows(4).hWnd)
                    Dim strBlue As String = WindowsEnumerator.WindowText(EditWindows(5).hWnd)

                    Dim Red, Green, Blue As Integer
                    If Integer.TryParse(strRed, Red) Then
                        If Integer.TryParse(strGreen, Green) Then
                            If Integer.TryParse(strBlue, Blue) Then
                                RaiseEvent CurrentColor(Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, Blue))
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
        End Select

        Return MyBase.HookProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class ApiWindow
    Public hWnd As IntPtr
    Public ClassName As String
    Public MainWindowTitle As String
End Class

Public Class WindowsEnumerator

    Private Delegate Function EnumCallBackDelegate(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

    Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumCallBackDelegate, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

    Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr, ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumCallBackDelegate, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

    Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpClassName As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer

    Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer

    Private Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer

    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As System.Text.StringBuilder) As Integer

    Private _listChildren As New List(Of ApiWindow)
    Private _listTopLevel As New List(Of ApiWindow)

    Private _topLevelClass As String = String.Empty
    Private _childClass As String = String.Empty

    Public Overloads Function GetTopLevelWindows() As ApiWindow()
        EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWindowProc, &H0)
        Return _listTopLevel.ToArray
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetTopLevelWindows(ByVal className As String) As ApiWindow()
        _topLevelClass = className
        Return Me.GetTopLevelWindows()
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetChildWindows(ByVal hwnd As Int32) As ApiWindow()
        _listChildren.Clear()
        EnumChildWindows(hwnd, AddressOf EnumChildWindowProc, &H0)
        Return _listChildren.ToArray
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetChildWindows(ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal childClass As String) As ApiWindow()
        _childClass = childClass
        Return Me.GetChildWindows(hwnd)
    End Function

    Private Function EnumWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32
        If GetParent(hwnd) = 0 AndAlso IsWindowVisible(hwnd) Then
            Dim window As ApiWindow = GetWindowIdentification(hwnd)
            If _topLevelClass.Length = 0 OrElse window.ClassName.ToLower() = _topLevelClass.ToLower() Then
                _listTopLevel.Add(window)
            End If
        End If
        Return 1
    End Function

    Private Function EnumChildWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32
        Dim window As ApiWindow = GetWindowIdentification(hwnd)
        If _childClass.Length = 0 OrElse window.ClassName.ToLower() = _childClass.ToLower() Then
            _listChildren.Add(window)
        End If
        Return 1
    End Function

    Private Function GetWindowIdentification(ByVal hwnd As Integer) As ApiWindow
        Dim classBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder(64)
        GetClassName(hwnd, classBuilder, 64)

        Dim window As New ApiWindow
        window.ClassName = classBuilder.ToString()
        window.MainWindowTitle = WindowText(hwnd)
        window.hWnd = hwnd
        Return window
    End Function

    Public Shared Function WindowText(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As String
        Const W_GETTEXT As Integer = &HD
        Const W_GETTEXTLENGTH As Integer = &HE

        Dim SB As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim length As Integer = SendMessage(hwnd, W_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
        If length > 0 Then
            SB = New System.Text.StringBuilder(length + 1)
            SendMessage(hwnd, W_GETTEXT, SB.Capacity, SB)
        End If
        Return SB.ToString
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: OH-MY-GOD, You are a API master, really I'm too impressed, you can't imagine how much I appreciate your help and your answer, the code is doing exactly what I need. Only one question, if I want to compile your class into a dll then which Framework version you recommend me to target in the project settings? (sorry if is a stupid question)

Comment: The code is using generic Lists so it needs at least .Net 2.0.  You could switch to ArrayLists if you want to go even lower to .Net 1.1.  Other than that, there's nothing special being used here to warrant a higher version of .Net.

Comment: Feel free to hit that checkmark if you feel the question is "solved".

Comment: Of course I mark your question, just I was little busy writting a new question about your class, take a look if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596853/adding-title-location-properties-to-this-custom-colordialog thankyou again and sorry about my english.