# Host a Dialog inside winforms User Control?

Tags: winforms

Is is possible to "host" a Dialog, inside of a UserControl?

In my case I want a ColorPicker, but with some extra TextBox and Buttons on the side.

Comment: Cleanly, and easily?...NO.  Is it "possible", sure.  Worth the work?...probably not.  I'd just roll my own form that has the functionality so you can completely customize it.

Comment: It's actually pretty simple, you can run the Dialog with `Task.Run()` and call `ShowDialog()`, `SetParent()` (to parent it to a Container) + `SetWindoPos()` (`SWP_NOSIZE` + `SWP_SHOWWINDOW`) to move it in place. When the Dialog is closed, read the `.Color` property and return this value or use a handler class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the choice was made. But it's kind of lame, you have to show **that** Dialog. You can find already built open source Controls that implement a Color selector in different ways, some quite *cool*.

Comment: @Jimi, haha...you just made a whole lot of assumptions there about the skill level of the author.  They might be able to do that, or they might not!  At any rate, to use `SetParent()` we need a window handle for the dialog, so now we need to either go hunting for it with a bunch of other APIs, or you need to inherit from ColorDialog so you can expose it.  Either way, this is not "pretty simple".  =)

Comment: @Idle_Mind Nooo, it's run in a Task. You can get the handle with FindWindowEx or UI Automation's `WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent`, since you know that it's class name will be `#32770` and the Process ID is the same as your app. It's just two lines of code (all right, 3 lines). The OP is a 12 years old member of SO, I assume that things like `SetParent` or `SetWindoPos` are  not exactly unheard of. Maybe I'll write some code to test, just for fun.

Comment: You might be interested in the [code I posted for this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595775/2330053) involving a ColorDialog.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Here, [a PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/HFCEXzJE) with some *instructions*: Just a very quick write (it doesn't really care about the initial *presentation*). Instructions inside. It just handles the selected Color. It uses UI Automation, so it can be modified to handle the Color selections while the Dialog is opened quite easily.  -- The code you linked is interesting.

Comment: @Jimi, Nice!...I'll play with it.  My code from 2013 was written that way because I never learned how to use UI Automation.  That's been on my "to do" list for quite some time...  ;)